# using an api if any exceptional error occur that will automatically create a ticket on Jira using vuejs

Tags: javascript, python, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuetify.js

i have hit the api through post man and it creates the ticket on jira  but now when i am using an index.js and writing the code in vuejs it shows the cors error

i dont understand the flow when i generate an demo error it shows nothing except cors error

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
import axios from 'axios';
Vue.config.errorHandler = function (err) {
  // Get the error details
  const errorMessage = err.message;
  const stackTrace = err.stack;
  console.log("error from vue event handler ===>", errorMessage, stackTrace);
  console.log(process.env)
  // Create the JIRA ticket
  const data = {
    fields: {
      project: {
        key: 'EE'
      },
      summary: errorMessage,
      description: stackTrace.toString(),
      issuetype: {
        id: '10004'
      }
    }
  };
  axios.post('https://errorgene.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/issue/', data, {
    auth: {
      username: 'syed.haider@voltro.com',
      password: 'iPUX7n9nk2VXyRBJOWysF202',
    },
    headers:{
      'X-Atlassian-Token':'no-check',
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log('JIRA ticket created successfully', response)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error('Error creating JIRA ticket:', error)
  });
}
new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 2):

First read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS

Cors only works when making a request from a browser so what you are doing with vue. When making a request with postman it does not come from the browser therefore there is no Corse error.

There are 2 ways to fix this for the atlassian api.

1: use oauth2 for authentication this is supported by atlassian and will not give you a cors error.

2: Create a small node api that does the request to the atlassian api, this will make it server to server so cors is not a problem then. After making the small node api you can then make a request from vue to this small node api and it will work.